# Join multiple Tables - Comment and Replies

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I try to create a query of questions and answer of different users. My goal is to join different tables together to create my desire result. Currently, the SQL query always generates the same content in the comment column, i.e. from the user who asked the question. UserA's answers are therefore not output at all. I changed the **INNER JOIN** with **LEFT/RIGHT**, then it would work, but then the question (comment) would be gone.

```
SELECT C.username UserQ
     , R.username UserA
     , C.commentID
     , D.Title
     , C.text Comment 
  FROM Comments C 
  JOIN Detail D 
    ON C.vID = D.vId 
  JOIN Search S 
    ON C.vID = S.vID 
  JOIN Replies R 
    ON C.commentID = R.CommentID_ParentID 
 WHERE D.categoryId = 25 
   AND S.searched_keyword = 'stackoverflow' 
 GROUP  
    BY UserQ
     , UserA
     , commentID
     , Title
     , Comment


Current Outcome:

UserQ       UserA     commentID    Title         Comment
Sven        Katja     213          Need Help     Hi, I need help
Sven        Sven      214          Answer1       Hi, I need help
Sven        Ben       215          Answer2       Hi, I need help
Tess        NULL      216          Soccer        I love soccer
Carl        Tanja     216          Question      Do I need SQL for jobs? 
Carl        Peter     216          Answer        Do I need SQL for jobs?
```

I also tried different approaches with the SQL statement **"UNION"**, but then there is a clear separation between UserQ and UserA, which means that one of the columns is always empty when the other is filled.

```
Desired Outcome:

UserQ       UserA     commentID    Title         Comment
Sven        Katja     213          Need Help     Hi, I need help
Sven        Sven      214          Answer1       Try to solve it like..
Sven        Ben       215          Answer2       You can also try...
Tess        NULL      216          Soccer        I love soccer
Carl        Tanja     216          Question      Do I need SQL for jobs? 
Carl        Peter     216          Answer        Yes...
```

Comment: please share source table question and comments sample data and its expected output

Comment: In your query you have `INNER JOIN Replies as R ON V.commentID = R.CommentID_ParentID`, what is `V` in this context, i.e. what is this an alias of?  Maybe you didn't give us the whole query?

Comment: @RichardHansell, oh sorry that what a spelling mistake. It should mean C instead of V

Comment: What application code is this? And see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry, well the code will execute in Python

Comment: Can we ignore the python for now?

Comment: Sure, the question was originally addressed to SQL.

Comment: Again: Please show/explain the tables. For instance: What does the `Detail` table represent? "Detail" of what? It has a column `Title`, so it looks like a question, but then the table would probably be named `Question` or `Request` or the like. So how is a `Detail` different from that? What are the table's columns? What is its unique key? Please edit your request and give us all the information on all tables used. Plus: What does a `vID` represent? Is a `Comment` a question or an answer or a comment on a question or an answer or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
SELECT C.username UserQ,
       R.username UserA,
       C.commentID,
       D.Title,
       C.text Comment
  FROM Comments C 
  JOIN Detail D 
    ON C.vID = D.vId 
  JOIN Search S 
    ON C.vID = S.vID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Replies R 
    ON C.commentID = R.CommentID_ParentID 
 WHERE D.categoryId = 25 
   AND S.searched_keyword = 'stackoverflow' 
 ORDER
    BY commentID,
       replyID
```

Actually, why do not you create an SQLfiddle with some example data?

Answer (score 0):

INER JOIN, OUTER JOIN, FULL JOIN, LEFT JOIN

http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/joins/